# Unpivot certain columns to certain row

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have a table with the following structure:

| ID | UID | C304 | C305 | C304_Value | C305_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1225 | 86 | 01 | 15 | 99 |
| 2 | 1226 | 89 | 06 | 10 | 15 |

I would like to have the output to be something like

| ID | UID | Col | Col_Value | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1225 | C304 | 86 | 99 |
| 1 | 1225 | C305 | 89 | 15 |

I've tried unpivot, but it will duplicate the columns per a row.

Is there a way to achieve this?

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT UID, Col, Col_Value,
C304_Value, C305_Value
--,*
FROM Input
--Unpivot(  Field_Values    
--              for field IN ([dfdf])) as PVT
unpivot (
Col_Value
for Col in (C304, C305)
) up
where UID = '1225'
```

Comment: Please explain the logic.  What happened to UID 1226, for instance?

Comment: I've just filtered it out on in the where clause

Comment: Then how do you get values from the second row?

Comment: So is `Value` the value of the *other* column? So for the row where it has a value of `'C304'` for `col`, the value of `Col_Value` is the value of `C304_Value` and `Value` is the value of `C305_Value`, but reversed when `col` has a value of `C305`?

Comment: @Larnu - that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you just want to unpivot the values.  I'm not sure what the last column is, but the basic idea is:

```
select t.id, t.uid, v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('C304', C304),
             ('C305', C305)
     ) v(col, col_value);
```

This does not return the results you specify, but I think it is what you are trying to do.

If the last column is just the "other" value, you would include that as well:

```
select t.id, t.uid, v.*
from t cross apply
     (values ('C304', C304, C305),
             ('C305', C305, C304)
     ) v(col, col_value, other_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some pretty odd logic, however, this seems to be what you are after. I prefer to use a `VALUES` table construct over the more restrictive `UNPIVOT` operator though:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int,
                            UID int,
                            C304 int,
                            C305 int,
                            C304_Value int,
                            C305_Value int);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable 
VALUES(1,1225,86,01,15,99),
      (2,1226,89,06,10,15);
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO

SELECT YT.ID,
       YT.UID,
       V.Col,
       V.Col_Value,
       V.[Value]
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(N'C304',YT.C304_Value,YT.C305_Value),
                        (N'C305',YT.C305_Value,YT.C304_Value))V(Col,Col_Value,[Value])
WHERE YT.ID = 1;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```